# Using *.bdc files in GoldenDict

Tags: dictionary, babylon

I use GoldenDict. it can read *.bgl files which are originally designed for Babylon dictionary, but it cannot read *.bdc files which are also Babylon dictionary format. Is there any way to convert *.bdc files to *.bgl files to use in GoldenDict?

Answer (score 2):

The project https://github.com/ilius/pyglossary tried to do that conversion but the developer seems to have abandoned the idea

BDC files are encrypted and proprietary files so it's even illegal to convert them

What i advice you is to search google with the file you want to convert and add bgl to your search request, you will probably find what you look for because most dictionary are old and they have been in bgl format before being distributed as bdc

Also there is a huge catalog of free bdc dic on http://www.babylon-software.com/free-dictionaries i guess you will find most of your bdc there in bgl format.